# Install Centos7 Kernel Offset

Tags: centos7

I'm trying to install Centos7 on my MSI laptop, with disk is SSD via USB boot. During the installing time, is not responding to me any message. See image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvZtu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

How did you make the USB? Check the [wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey):

> You must write to the entire device and not a partition on it (so,
>   /dev/sdb not /dev/sdb1)
>
> When asked for the media to install from, select "hard disk" and then
>   the device corresponding to the USB key.
>
> Make sure you select as destination the device corresponding to the
>   USB key (/dev/sdb in the above example) and not a partition (such as
>   /dev/sdb1)

Make sure you not using unetbootin, it wouldn't work!